# What is the difference between Miner Tip and maxPriorityFeePerGas

Tags: mining, fees, mev

Yesterday I noticed 2 arbitrage transactions on Uniswap V3 in the same block and pools:

1)https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1933479aad430fc3b0acfb9394d138e62d19d1a15437a52a807ca4af9bad7591
2)https://etherscan.io/tx/0x991bf114816ce66adf141271629e3fc7edf3ef76ed4bbf2bfbf69c9d419c0874

In the first one I see Max Priority: 1.5 Gwei (As I know it's called Miner Tip)
In the second one I see Max Priority: 0 Ether (no Miner Tip) , but TRANSFER  0.136949999802102896 Ether to Eden Network: Builder. If I'm not wrong, it's a miner, so it's a tip too, but rather more than 1.5 gwei.

The first one transaction won because Position In Block: 0 and paid only 1.5 Gwei.
The second one transaction had Position In Block: 1 for 0.13 eth.

I really tried to google everything about miner tips, but there are only articles about maxPriorityFeePerGas and maxFeePerGas, no info about this direct fees to miners. May be somebody knows how they do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can either directly pay the miner(actually Fee Recipient in the PoS world, miner is PoW) by tipping ETH to `block.coinbase` or indirectly pay by burning gas, the miner will receive:

```
gasUsed * (Min(maxFeePerGas, baseFee + maxPriorityFeePerGas) - baseFee)
```